# How can I get this code to function the same without the constructor?

Tags: java, algorithm, constructor, printwriter

I am very new to programming and I am attempting to modify a heap algorithm that I found online.  From a previous question, I was able to get the code to work with a PrintWriter, but when attempting to use this function as a method in another class, I get an error because of the constructor.  How can this code be modified to work the same, simply without a constructor?

I am not very familiar with programming, so I have tried looking at previous questions.  Somehow, I thought of using a nested class (not sure how they work), but to no avail.  The method worked when it was in its own class.

```
// Should be within a class

private PrintWriter _pw;

// This is the part that needs to go.
public HeapAlgo(PrintWriter pw) {
   this._pw = pw;
}

public void heapPermutation(String a[], int size, int n) throws IOException { 
// if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
// permutation 
    if (size == 1) 
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
            System.out.println(a[i] + "");
            this._pw.println(a[i] + ""); 
        }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
        heapPermutation(a, size-1, n); 

        // if size is odd, swap first and last 
        // element 
        if (size % 2 == 1) { 
            String temp = a[0]; 
            a[0] = a[size-1]; 
            a[size-1] = temp; 
        }

        // If size is even, swap ith and last 
        // element 
        else { 
           String temp = a[i]; 
           a[i] = a[size-1]; 
           a[size-1] = temp; 
        } 
    }

}

public void heap() throws IOException 
{
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("note.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
File temp = new File("code.txt");
Scanner file = new Scanner(temp);

String substring = "";

    String a[] = new String[4];
  a[0] = "" + file.nextLine(); 
  a[1] = "" + file.nextLine();
  a[2] = "" + file.nextLine();
  a[3] = "" + file.nextLine();



HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo(pw); // Pass in a writer
obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length);
pw.close();
}
```

When I run the methods inside a large class I get an error saying \
"error: invalid method declaration; return type required".

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I am trying to code this constructor:

```
    public CodeRunner() 
    { 
    random(); 
    HeapAlgo.heap(//not sure if anything should go here); 
    algorithm(); 
    }
```

where random() creates random strings, and the algorithm function performs an algorithm on all possible iterations of the random string. I am trying to make objects for each set of random strings.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the methods inside a large class"?

Comment: If you don't want to pass a PrintWriter then how are you going to get the sorting result

Comment: Are you running `.heap()` on an instance of `HeapAlgo` or the class itself? It looks like you'll need to instantiate an instance and run `.heap()` on it. I'll update my answer. Once I do, go ahead and try that out.

Comment: Okay, actually, I'm going to need some more clarification. Once you run `HeapAlgo.heap()`, I presume you will need access to the result (in your case either the `HeapAlgo` object that is inside `heap()` or the `PrintWriter` inside the `HeapAlgo` object). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the HeapAlgo object.

Comment: Ok check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following elements should be within a class called `HeapAlgo`:

1. The private variable declaration

```java
private PrintWriter _pw;
```

2. The constructor itself

```java
public HeapAlgo(PrintWriter pw)
```

3. The heapPermutation function

```java
public void heapPermutation(String a[], int size, int n) throws IOException
```

The last remaining method, `heap()`, should be placed in some other class (possibly where your `main()` function is) and called from there.

Alternatively, you could indeed use an inner class. Wrap all the code you provided in a class (maybe called `Heap`) then wrap the aforementioned three elements in an inner class called `HeapAlgo`. Something like this (I very quickly typed this up, so there may be errors you need to fix):

```java
public class HeapUtil {
    public class HeapAlgo {
        private PrintWriter _pw;

        // This is the part that needs to go.
        public HeapAlgo(PrintWriter pw) {
           this._pw = pw;
        }

        public PrintWriter getPrintWriter(){
            return _pw;
        }

        public void heapPermutation(String a[], int size, int n) throws IOException { 
        // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained 
        // permutation 
            if (size == 1) 
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
                    System.out.println(a[i] + "");
                    this._pw.println(a[i] + ""); 
                }

            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
                heapPermutation(a, size-1, n); 

                // if size is odd, swap first and last 
                // element 
                if (size % 2 == 1) { 
                    String temp = a[0]; 
                    a[0] = a[size-1]; 
                    a[size-1] = temp; 
                }

                // If size is even, swap ith and last 
                // element 
                else { 
                   String temp = a[i]; 
                   a[i] = a[size-1]; 
                   a[size-1] = temp; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    public static HeapAlgo heap() throws IOException 
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("note.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        File temp = new File("code.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(temp);

        String substring = "";

        String a[] = new String[4];
        a[0] = "" + file.nextLine(); 
        a[1] = "" + file.nextLine();
        a[2] = "" + file.nextLine();
        a[3] = "" + file.nextLine();

        HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo(pw); // Pass in a writer
        obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Note that in this case, if you would like to use `HeapAlgo` outside of this class file, you will need to use `Heap.HeapAlgo`.

---

Edit: Try out the code above (I edited it). There may be a few errors since I didn't actually run it.

Usage is as follows:

```java
public CodeRunner(){ 
    random(); 
    // heapAlgo is the heap object
    HeapAlgo heapAlgo = HeapUtil.heap(); 
    // this gives you access to the PrintWriter inside the HeapAlgo
    PrintWriter printWriter = heapAlgo.getPrintWriter();
    // do your other stuff
    algorithm(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want to use this code as a method in the construction of a more complex object, so when I tried to separate the classes and called HeapAlgo.heap(), I got an error saying "non-static method heap() cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: I'm going to need a bit more context to be able to effectively help you then. Can you provide any more code (i.e. where you are attempting to call `HeapAlgo.heap()`) and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure.  I am trying to code this constructor:  public CodeRunner()
   {
      random();
      HeapAlgo.heap();
      algorithm();
   }  where random creates random strings, and the algorithm function performs an algorithm on all possible iterations of the random string.  I am trying to make objects for each random strings.

Comment: @BoxerDog If you need to add more information than the comment space will allow, just edit your question and I'll take a look up there.